# Installing Ubuntu on clean harddrive?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I'm currently having some issues. I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my brothers' computer that has a hard drive with no operating system on and it doesn't ask me to use the whole disk, It pops up the Installation Type and I can click Install Now or it gives me a root error, And if I click +, -, or Change it freezes! Can I have some help? EDIT:When I click Install Now it pops up "No root file system is defined. Plase correct this from the partitioning menu" And allthe options are shaded out, except +, -, and Change... And each of them will freeze the computer.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty computer"? Is there anything at all inside the case? Is there an HDD? What kind? How large? What's on it?

Comment: It has a HDD, This is my computer http://www.amazon.com/Compaq-15-6-Laptop-320GB-CQ58-bf9WM/dp/B00A2T9ZNW

Comment: What is that "root error" that pops up? Are you using a CD or a USB to install Ubuntu? What software did you use to make the CD/USB bootable?

Comment: USB, Universal USB Installer, and it says the Root File is Undefined I bbelieve

Comment: "*...and I can click Install Now **or** it gives me a root error...*" Is that to say, when you click *Install Now*, you don't get an error? If so, you should just click *Install Now*. If not, please [edit] your question to provide a considerably more detailed description of exactly what's happening. In particular, if you're not sure about the complete and exact text of all error messages, you can try it again to see. Also, have you checked the md5sum of the iso image you used, and verified the installation medium? Step 1 of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076) explains how to do that.

Comment: Alright, I did.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Put the Ubuntu Usb into the Usb.

Restart your computer.

You should see a welcome screen prompting you to choose your language and giving you the option to try it from the Usb.

After the session live load.

Start the installation.

Select advanced or manual disk partitioning, for to create a custom set of partitions for installing.

On a default installation of Ubuntu 14.04, the installer creates just two partitions; the first for /, the root directory, and the second for Swap.

When creating partitions for installing any desktop Linux distribution, my recommendation is to create the following three partitions:

/, the root directory. The bulk of the programs used for running the system will be installed here and where programs critical for booting the system will reside.

Swap, unformatted disk space for use as virtual memory.

/home, the partition where your home directory will be located. In the course of using the system, files and folders you create will reside in various folders here.

To get to the advanced partitioning tool, select the Something Else option and click Forward.

The target disk is a new one and it has not been initialized, select it and click the New Partition Table button.

Select the free space and click the Add button.

The installer will create the first partition as a primary partition. And that first partition, following the recommendation made earlier, should be mounted at /. The default file system for / on Ubuntu is ext4, it will be /dev/sda1. As more applications are installed on a running system, disk usage will grow, so you want to be very generous here – if you have disk space to spare.

Now that / has been created, select the free space and click on Add to create other partitions.

Note that this step will have to be repeated for all other partitions.

The second partition will be for Swap. The installer will attempt to create it as a logical partition, the first logical partition of an extended partition is /dev/sda5.

Select Swap area from the Use as dropdown menu. The Mount point menu will be disabled because Swap does not need a mount point.

The final partition will be for /home. The file system is ext4, and you may use the available disk space here.

Back to the main manual partitioning window, you can see all the partitions just created. Before you click Install Now, you have to determine where GRUB, the boot loader, will be installed. On a standalone installation, the best location is the default – in the Master Boot Record of the disk /dev/sda.